# MOOC deadline aggregator

Tags: web-apps, educational, mooc

I am listening to several MOOCs. I am looking for a deadline aggregator that would:

- list all upcoming deadlines (quiz, assignments, programming exercises, exams, etc.) for the courses I have registered,
- support at least Coursera, bonus point if it supports edX and other MOOC platforms,
- free if possible.

Such an aggregator would probably be a web service, but I'm also OK if it's an application for Windows 7.

Comment: Is there a public source of information or eventually even an API where such a program could get those deadlines?

Comment: Probably need to register for each course (free).

Comment: If you have to register it is really unlikely that such a web service exists.